# How to define XSD element to have multiple children, all of which are simple and only have attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to define a section of my XSD in which the following XML would be valid:

```
<machine>
    <timing offset="3s" period="20s"/>

    <!-- <machine> actually has many child elements, all of them are like <timing>
         and only have attributes -->
</machine>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
<xs:element name="machine">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <!-- Definition for the <timing> child element. -->
            <xs:element name="timing" type="timing_type"/>
            <xs:complexType name="timing_type">
                <xs:attribute name="offset" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="period" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:complexType>

            <!-- Definitions for the other <machine> child elements... -->
        </xs:all>
    </xd:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

On the line that reads `<xs:complexType name="timing_type">`, I get the following error message:

> Error resolving component 'timing_type'. It was detected that 'timing_type' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/ 2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:////mySchema.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'timing_type' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:////mySchema.xsd'.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? How do I just define a whole bunch of children for `<machine>` that are all simple, have no children, and only have attributes? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be learning XSD, it may be easier to build more complete XML samples, and then use some tool to generate an XSD from all those sample XMLs. From that generated XSD you can learn a lot, and it should make it easier for you to change it incrementally to better fit your goals.

The error is that you cannot have a named type nested under anything other than an `xs:schema` or an `xs:redefine`.

So your snipped would be correct if you would look as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="machine">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <!-- Definition for the <timing> child element. -->
                <xs:element name="timing" type="timing_type"/>
                <!-- Definitions for the other <machine> child elements... -->
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="timing_type">
        <xs:attribute name="offset" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="period" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

A problem you might run into is related to the use of `xs:all` instead of `xs:sequence` or `xs:choice`. in XSD 1.0, `xs:all` is very picky in that you can't have more than one occurrence for the `timing` element.

The XSD below was generated by a tool. It uses a **sequence** compositor (instead of **all**) which would allow for the variation I've added (maxOccurs="unbounded")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="machine">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="timing" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="offset" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            <xsd:attribute name="period" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

If you add to the mix another type of element (as you suggested) and you wish to allow for any number of such element, individually occurring more than once and in any order, then the model below would work. The thing to note here is `xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="machine">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="timing">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="offset" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            <xsd:attribute name="period" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="cycle">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="duration" type="xsd:positiveInteger" use="required" />
            <xsd:attribute name="period" type="xsd:positiveInteger" use="required" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>          
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks @Petru Gardea (+1) - however, even after moving the `timing_type` to be right about the closing `</xs:schema>` element, I am still getting the same exact error. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Then there is more than what you've shown. Did you try the first XSD I've posted? Are you getting an error with it? Just in case, the schemas I've posted are valid. I can help you if you are able to share the XSD somehow. If you don't want to make it public, you can send it to the support address posted on my website and I'll take it from there.

Comment: Thanks @Petru Gardea (+1 again!) - I just sent you an email, please let me know if you didn't receive it! Thanks again!

Comment: Problem solved (sent you an email). It is related to the use of the default namespace. The funny thing is, now that I read the error message with different eyes, it all makes sense. Oh well...